# What phonetic language an dictionary is supported by Siri on iOS?

Tags: iphone, siri, ios

I want to convince Siri to properly pronounce and recognise some of my contacts.

I know that I need to tweak the 3 fields: `Phonetic First Name`, `Phonetic Last Name` and `Nickname` for that.

Still, I am missing some very important information:

- What phonetic language does it use as it does not seem to be [IPA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Phonetic_Alphabet)
- Where can I find the list of possible sounds and their letters

Answer (score 1):

Just like it sounds.

Obama => Oh Ba mu